# calculations between two Multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, matrix

I have this code:

```
$id = new matrix(array(0=>array(1,0.5,3), 1=>array(2,1,4), 2=>array(1/3,1/4,1)));

$soma = $id->times($id)->sumRows();
```

That outputs this:

```
matrix Object ( [numbers] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 12.75 [1] => 22.3333333333 [2] => 4.83333333333 ) ) [numColumns] => 3 [numRows] => 1 )
```

and:

```
$total = $id->times($id)->sumRows()->sumTotal($id);
```

That outputs this:

```
matrix Object ( [numbers] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 39.9166666667 ) ) [numColumns] => 3 [numRows] => 1 )
```

Now, i am trying to make:

```
foreach ($soma as $value){
    $final = (int)$value/(int)$total;
    print_r ((int)$final);
}
```

The output will be 000.

Must be:

```
12.75/39.9166666667 = 0,3269230769230769 
22.3333333333 / 39.9166666667 = ...
and so on
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `matrix` class. Can you post a link to documentation or some other resource about it?

Comment: Here: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/5793-PHP-Perform-operations-to-manipulate-matrices.html - thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am not a member of that web site. Also, because external links break, it is preferable if you include all relevant sources in your question.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Here is the the class in page of the author: http://www.pabsta.qc.ca/matrix/examples.php - but it is needed the class for this particular question ? well, i don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is solved :

documentation:

```
get_data($..)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just some ideas, without really knowing much about the `matrix` class...

1. All those `(int)`s should probably be `(float)`s, as you seem to want a non-int answer.
2. `$value` is itself an object, so you'll probably need to use `$value['numbers'][0][0 or 1 or 2]`. Same goes for `$total`.